# Cannot use HttpHeaderCredentials in gradle publishing

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, maven-publish

I'm trying to bublish release into GitLab. I've configured gradle task as discribed in official GitLab docs.

```
 maven {
            name = "GitLab"
            url = uri("https://" + System.getenv("CI_SERVER_HOST") + "/api/v4/projects/" + System.getenv("CI_PROJECT_ID") + "/packages/maven")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                header( HttpHeaderAuthentication )
            }
        }
```

And, in pipeline, it fails with:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':publishLibraryPublicationToLaptevTechRepository' (type 'PublishToMavenRepository').
  - In plugin 'org.gradle.api.publish.maven.plugins.MavenPublishPlugin$Inject' type 'org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository' property 'credentials.username' doesn't have a configured value.
    
    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'credentials.username'.
      2. Mark property 'credentials.username' as optional.
```